# matrix method for solving system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $Ax=B$ be a system of linear equations, where $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix and $x,B$ are $n \times 1$ vectors. my book says that if $\det A=0$ and Adj$A$. $B=O$ (where Adj denotes the adjoint of $A$ and $O$ is the zero matrix of $n \times n$ order), then the system may be either consistent or inconsistent,how can it be inconsistent?

Comment: A and B are matrices

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Thanks ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the $3\times 3$ system $A\cdot x=B$ with
$$
  A=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&5\\-1&-2&-5\\3&6&15\end{pmatrix}
  \qquad\text{and}\qquad
 B=\begin{pmatrix}4\\2\\0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Now $A$ has rank$~1$, so $\def\Adj{\operatorname{Adj}}\Adj A=0$, and certainly $\Adj A\cdot B=0$; nevertheless the system is inconsistent.

In fact this situation is typical: if $\det A=0$ but $\Adj A\neq0$, then the system is consistent if and only if $\Adj A\cdot B=0$; however if $\Adj A=0$ then the latter equation of course does not tell anything about whether the system is consistent. To see this claim, note that $\det A=0$ and $\Adj A\neq0$ together imply that the rank of $A$ is $n-1$, and $\Adj A\cdot A=\det(A)I=0$ implies that the kernel of $\Adj A$ contains the image of $A$, but since the former has dimension${}<n$ and the latter has dimension $\operatorname{rk}A=n-1$, the two subspaces are equal. Now $A\cdot x=B$ is consistent if any only if $B$ is in this subspace $\ker(\Adj A)$, i.e., if and only if $\Adj A\cdot B=0$.

The situation $\Adj A=0$ can arise for $2\times2$ matrices, but only when $A=0$, which is why I gave the more interesting looking example above.

Comment: can such a situation be created for a 2✖2 system

Comment: @PRATIKKUMBHARE: yes, but see my addition.